# Поле статуса с параметром editable = False

Tags: python, django

Мне необходимо грамотно описать поле статуса, которое должно быть неизменяемым, но должно отображаться в админ-панели в списке объектов(list_display).

Зачастую для поля статуса делают choices, но так-как оно будет неизменяемым, я не вижу в этом смысла.

**Вариант 1:**

```
# enum


class ModelStatus(IntEnum):
    initial = 1
    processing = 2
    failed = 3
    success = 4


class SomeModel(models.Model):
    status = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=ModelStatus.initial.value, editable=False)

    @property
    def status_display(self):
        """Для использования с целью отображения в админ-панели"""
        return ModelStatus(self.status).name
```

**Вариант 2**:

```
# strings


STATUS_INITIAL = "INITIAL"
STATUS_PROCESSING = "PROCESSING"
STATUS_FAILED = "FAILED"
STATUS_SUCCESS = "SUCCESS"


class SomeModel(models.Model):
    status = models.CharField(max_lenght=10, default=STATUS_INITIAL, editable=False)
```

Возможно есть еще какие-либо варианты, посоветуйте, пожалуйста.

Comment: В ModelAdmin для этого есть свойство [readonly_fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.readonly_fields), трогать саму модель не надо

Comment: Вы не поняли суть вопроса. Саму модель как раз таки надо трогать, Вы описали то, как отображать ее поле в админке, но вопрос о том, как описать это поле.

Comment: Его никак не нужно описывать, вы уже сами предложили два рабочих варианта, они вас чем-то не устраивают?

Comment: неа, они вполне норм. но какой из них лучше? они абсолютно идентичны в работе, но единственное, что первый вариант я увидел в opensource и не знаю почему этот варик для разрабов показался предпочтительнее второго. Подскажите, пожалуйста.